# How should I deal with this specific abuse report?

Tags: iptables, firewall, openvpn, centos7, port

Today , I have received an abuse report for one of my servers which is a CentOS 7 server with OpenVPN installed on it and it's using iptables firewall . The abuse reports basically says that a VPN client is doing brute force attacks on SSH port 22 . Now what I want to do is that I want to block VPN traffic to destination port 22 ! I mean that I want a client to fail connecting to SSH port 22 when he is connected to my VPN server . I have tried so many rules so far and I haven't been able to stop it so far . Here are the ones I have tried so far :

```
iptables -A FORWARD -o tun0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -o tun0 -p udp -m udp --dport 22 -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -s 10.8.0.0/24 -p tcp --destination-port 22 -j DROP
```

Can anyone please tell me what is the correct syntax to achieve what I'm looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the correct syntax was indeed the following :

```
iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.8.0.0/24 -p tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
```

the problem was that there were some other rules interfering with the above .